# C# asp.NET displaying output of a query to screen. Error: 'System.ArgumentException' in Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

First post here. I'm trying to create a website that fetches data from an Oracle database and returns some tables. I was able to connect my database fine and made a `DataConnector` that returns a list of `CodeDesc` objects. My main problem right now is simply displaying that data to the screen, preferably in the form of a drop down list but I'm using a `GridView` for now.

Here's my front end:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataConnector dc = new DataConnector();
    GridView2.DataSource = dc.getCodeTypes();
    GridView2.DataBind();
}
```

When I click the button, nothing is generated and the debugger only says "Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in Oracle.DataAccess.dll" Any help would be appreciated. This is my first time doing web development and it's been a struggle to get even this far. I'm using Visual Studio 2015

Back End:

```
//Create datatable to get info from db & return results
public List<CodeDesc> getCodeTypes()
{
    try
    {
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connString);
        con.Open();

       string query = "select id, descr from code_desc where code_type_id = 0";

        // Create the OracleCommand
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        // Execute command, create OracleDataReader object
        OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        List<CodeDesc> L = new List<CodeDesc>(); 

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            CodeDesc c = new CodeDesc();
            c.id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            c.description = reader.GetString(1);
            L.Add(c);
        }
        // Clean up
        reader.Dispose();
        cmd.Dispose();
        con.Dispose();

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(L);
        return L;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      // catch clause here...
    }
}
```

CodeDesc:

```
public class CodeDesc
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: look at inner exception of your error. It's contain more detail of error

Comment: You never set the query string as the CommandText to be executed. No good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never set the query string to the CommandText property of the OracleCommand. Of course this can only result in an exception when you try to execute your command.

Said that, remember that every disposable object should be enclosed in a using statement. This is very important in case of exceptions because the correct closing and disposing is executed automatically exiting from the using block

```
public List<CodeDesc> getCodeTypes()
{
    try
    {
        List<CodeDesc> L = new List<CodeDesc>(); 
        string query = "select id, descr from code_desc where code_type_id = 0";
        using(OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connString))
        using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            // Execute command, create OracleDataReader object
            using(OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   CodeDesc c = new CodeDesc();
                   c.id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                   c.description = reader.GetString(1);
                   L.Add(c);
                }
            }
       }
       System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(L);
       return L;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm still a bit confused. Looking at your code, where do you set the CommandText property of the query string? I did not do that already with the line "cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;"? In any case, changing my code to include the blurb you provided gives me the same problem.

Comment: No, CommandType informs the OracleCommand if you are executing a text query or a stored procedure and by default is already CommandType.Text. Probably you mean cmd.CommandText. In any case when I build the OracleCommand I use the constructor that receives the command text to be executed and the connection (avoiding two lines of code _cmd.CommandText  = query; cmd.Connection = con;_)

Comment: And about the error. Try to look at the Exception.InnerException property (Click View Details on the message) Usually this property contains additional info that makes clearer the problem.

Comment: Ah I get it now thanks. But I don't see a View Details in my debug/output window...

Comment: Try to write it out in the catch block then.... IE: _Console.WriteLine("InnerException=[" + ex.InnerException?.Message + "]");_

Comment: Can you use the debugger to set a breakpoint and check on which line the exception is thrown?

Comment: I'll check it out. First time using VS and all this but I'll make another question or contact you if I can't figure it out. Thanks so much for being patient with me through all this! I've upvoted your original answer.